# How to load obj-model using web url in aframe

Tags: three.js, augmented-reality, aframe

I need to load `.obj` and `.mtl` files from a web URL for my Web app. But I'm not able to find a clear example. Example code would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Use the [obj-model](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/obj-model.html#sidebar) component. Example included. You will have to share your code for more specific answers. Glitch is a good option https://glitch.com/~aframe

Comment: Thank you diego for the reply. I know we can use obj-model component. But can we use it to load objects from poly-toolkit provided by google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From A-Frame's docs example:

```
 <a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <a-asset-item id="tree-obj" src="/path/to/tree.obj"></a-asset-item>
    <a-asset-item id="tree-mtl" src="/path/to/tree.mtl"></a-asset-item>
  </a-assets>

  <a-entity obj-model="obj: #tree-obj; mtl: #tree-mtl"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

You can use a URL in the src.